# How to activate (make visible / enable / show) Selection Pane in PowerPoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010, powerpoint-2007, powerpoint-2013

In PowerPoint 2013, the Selection pane properties are available from a CommandBar object as follows:

```
Application.CommandBars("Selection")
```

(note that for PowerPoint 2010 and 2007 the name is "Selection and Visibility")

When using Alt+F10 in the UI to show the Selection Pane, the following two properties are toggled to true:

```
Application.CommandBars("Selection").Visible
Application.CommandBars("Selection").Enabled
```

However, when attempting to set these to true programmatically, the .Visible=True statement causes an unspecified automation error to occur and the .Enabled=True statement executes but doesn't change the state of this property.

But, and this is the weird part, if Alt+F10 is used to show and hide the Selection Pane when PowerPoint first runs, the two lines of code work! I checked all the properties before and after Alt+F10 and only the .Visible and .Enabled ones are toggled.

How can I show the Selection Pane reliably and preferably without having to go down the SendKeys route?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to show it try:

```
    If Not CommandBars.GetPressedMso("SelectionPane") Then CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SelectionPane")
```

Comment: Thanks John. That works for 2013, 2010 and 2007 without any change :-)